# Laravel 7 jQuery blocking submit button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I have contact form for sending e-mails. When i adding jQuery no matters what version and i also tried downloaded jQuery and CDN  submit don't work in my contact form, nothing happens. In dev-tools don't have any errors. When i commenting out jQuery, everything works perfect. But i need both of them - contact form for site visitors and jQuery for my mobile menu. Maby there is another way to trigger action route with method=post?

Here is my blade

```
<form action="{{url('/sendmail')}}" method="post" id="contact">
    @csrf
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <fieldset>
                <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Jūsu vārds..." required="">
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <fieldset>
                <input name="email" type="text" class="form-control" id="email" pattern="[^ @]*@[^ @]*"
                       placeholder="Jūsu e-pasts..." required="">
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <fieldset>
                <input name="subject" type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" placeholder="Temats..." required="">
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <fieldset>
                <textarea name="message" rows="6" class="form-control" id="message" placeholder="Jūsu ziņa..."
                          required=""></textarea>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <fieldset>
                <button type="submit" id="form-submit" class="filled-button">Sūtīt ziņu</button>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And here is my route list

```
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@index');
Route::get('/kontakti', 'PagesController@contacts');
Route::post('/sendmail', 'MailController@sendMail')->name('send');
```

On other older Laravel versions this works fine, but in Laravel 7 it's not working.

UPDATE: here is script list for this template and seems that owl carousel is doing this error

```
<script src="{{asset('scripts/vendors/jquery-3.4.1.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('scripts/vendors/jquery.hoverIntent.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('scripts/vendors/perfect-scrollbar.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('scripts/vendors/jquery.easing.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('scripts/vendors/wow.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('scripts/vendors/parallax.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('scripts/vendors/isotope.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('scripts/vendors/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('scripts/vendors/packery-mode.pkgd.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('scripts/vendors/owl-carousel.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('scripts/vendors/jquery.appear.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('scripts/vendors/jquery.countTo.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('scripts/main.js')}}"></script>
```

Comment: There is not enough information to help you. Is there a live version we can check? Are you adding any other JavaScript files to the page? jQuery alone wouldn't block your form from being submitted.

Comment: @fromvega i added script list. I tried to comment out one by one script and seems that owl-carousel is key for this problem. Live version is at aliseswonderland.lv/kontakti

Answer (score 0):

Check in your browser if any request is being send. In Chrome of Firefox you can see this in developer tools network tab.

Also try to change your action to:

```
action="{{ route('send') }}"
```